# How to shuffle button positions when mouse is on it?

Tags: java, user-interface, button, mouse

I was wondering if anyone could help because I have searched high and low on the internet and even asked one of my mentors and they couldnt figure it out either.

Basically this is what needs to be done: On initialisation, the application should  randomly choose where to locate the "Click Me" button. When the mouse moves over the click me button it should move to a random location(shuffle the buttons) so the user is forever chasing the click me button and should never be able to click it.

I managed to get the buttons to shuffle places on initialisation by putting the buttons in an arraylist and adding the arraylist to the panel then shuffling the buttons, but I cannot get them to do it again when the mouse is over the 'click me' button.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.*;



public class Chase extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

JButton plain1, plain2, plain3, plain4, plain5, plain6, plain7, plain8, click;

ArrayList<JButton> buttons;

JPanel panelButtons;


 public Chase(){

 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

 panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

 setTitle("Catch me if you can!");
 setContentPane(panel);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 panelButtons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 4, 4));

 buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

 plain1 = new JButton();
 plain2 = new JButton();
 plain3 = new JButton();
 plain4 = new JButton();
 plain5 = new JButton();
 plain6 = new JButton();
 plain7 = new JButton();
 plain8 = new JButton();
 click = new JButton("Click Me");


 buttons.add(plain1);
 buttons.add(plain2);
 buttons.add(plain3);
 buttons.add(plain4);
 buttons.add(plain5);
 buttons.add(plain6);
 buttons.add(plain7);
 buttons.add(plain8);
 buttons.add(click);

 Collections.shuffle(buttons);

 for(JButton jb:buttons){
    panelButtons.add(jb);
 }

 panel.add(panelButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);


 pack();
 setSize(500, 300);
 setVisible(true);


 click.addMouseListener(this);


}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
   //this is what I need to figure out.
   Collections.shuffle(buttons);

 }




public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}


 public static void main(String[] args) {


     Chase chase = new Chase();
  }

 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity lets create function 'initPanel()' and put your code there (and of course call it in constructor):

```
public void initPanel() {

    Collections.shuffle(buttons);

    for(JButton jb:buttons){
        panelButtons.add(jb);
    }

    panel.add(panelButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    pack();
    setSize(500, 300);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Then all you need, is clear current panel, and initialize it again, when mouse is over button:

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
    //this is what I need to figure out.

    panel.removeAll();
    initPanel();

}
```

I hope this works)

P.S. Sometimes, you may experience button not shuffling, it is because, shuffling will give same 'index' for "Click me", so its position will not change (others will though)

Comment: Thank you it worked. I tried something like this actually before but i didnt know what to code after removing the panel components. But yeah it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with only one button and a absolute positioning.

The idea is just to compute a new random location that is still into the boundaries of the container.

```
class ClickMe extends JPanel {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    ClickMe() {
        setLayout(null);
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
                // Change location within the bondaries of the button container
                button.setLocation(
                    rand.nextInt(0, ClickMe.this.getWidth()),
                    rand.nextInt(0, ClickMe.this.getHeight())
                );
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 60);
        add(button);
    }
}
```